# I can't delete loading.tsx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, frontend, next.js13

I'm working on a project with Next.js
I added `loading.tsx` inside the app directory, but when I try to delete it, I get an error;

`Caused by: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)`

Import trace for requested module:
`./src/app/loading.tsx`

After deleting it, I am unable to bring up the application

Comment: would it be possible for you to add your next.config.js file here? Also wanted to make sure that you have tried killing your app server and restarting it? Also try removing .next dir as well!

Comment: We have solved this error with remove the .next folder. But I can't understand why I'm having this problem. @HarshTuwar

Answer (score 1):

Please make make sure that you have tried killing your app server and restarting it? Also try removing `.next` dir as well!

The `.next` folder is generated by Next.js using the build process and contains the compiled output, which includes the code for the server, client and other build artifacts. If this becomes corrupted or contains outdated files, it can lead to various errors including the one you are seeing.

When we remove the `.next` folder, we are effectively starting with a clean slate.

Hope this helps!